# Update table cell value on button click in Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap table. Just before the table I have a button and a textbox. After input any number in the textbox and click on the generate button, I want to update the "Bill Amount" column of each row with the textbox value. How can I do this?

```
<div>
Amount : <input type="number" class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount" placeholder="Amount">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="generateBill()">Generate</button>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>                    
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col"><input type="checkbox" [checked]="isAllCheckBoxChecked()" (change)="checkAllCheckBox($event)"></th>
        <th scope="col">Code</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Type</th>
        <th scope="col">Category</th>
        <th scope="col">Shop No</th>
        <th scope="col">Shop Name</th>                                        
        <th scope="col">Bill Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let member of memberBillLists; let i = index">
        <td scope="row">{{ member.Id }}</td>
        <td scope="row"><input type="checkbox" value="{{member.Id}}" [(ngModel)]="memberBillLists[i].Checked"></td>
        <td>{{member.Code}}</td>
        <td>{{member.Name}}</td>
        <td>{{member.Type}}</td>            
        <td>{{member.Category}}</td>
        <td>{{member.ShopNo}}</td>
        <td>{{member.ShopName}}</td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="memberBillLists[i].BillAmount"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind the input to a variable in your component file using two way binding. Then inside the `generateBill()` method you access memberBillLists array and update the bill amount with the amount you get from the two way binded value.